# File upload no longer works after upgrading from RESTEasy 2.4.3 to 3.0.1

Tags: java, client, resteasy, jaxb2

After upgrading from Resteasy 2.4 to 3.0.5. my file upload is no longer working. Here are the relevant bits.

The interface:

```
  @POST
  @ClientResponseType(entityType = JAXBModule.class)
  @Path("/upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Response upload(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form);
```

The FileUploadForm class

```
public class FileUploadForm {

  @FormParam("file")
  @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  private InputStream data;

  @FormParam("user")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String user;

  @FormParam("password")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String password;

  @FormParam("filename")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String filename;

  public FileUploadForm() {
  }

  public InputStream getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(InputStream data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
  }

  public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
  }
```

The client:

```
ResteasyClientBuilder rsb = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
ResteasyClient rsc = rsb.build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = rsc.target(BASEURL);
ModuleArchiveService client target.proxy(ModuleArchiveService.class);
FileUploadForm upload = new FileUploadForm();
upload.setUser("joe");
upload.setPassword("pwd");
upload.setFilename("image.jpg");
String fileToUpload = "testdata/image.jpg";
upload.setData(new FileInputStream(fileToUpload));
Response response = client.upload(upload);
```

The error message:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:102)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.upload(Unknown Source)
at nz.org.riskscape.archive.rest.LiveModuleArchiveServiceTest.testUploadFile(LiveModuleArchiveServiceTest.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: nz.org.riskscape.archive.rest.domain.FileUploadForm
….
```

I have resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.5.Final.jar in the class path. I am using Java 7 and Tomcat 7.0.42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a very well know bug, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-954. I am hoping it will be indeed fixed by the next release in the new year

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jaxrs-api-3.0.5.Final.jar in the class path?